# Sharepoint column take value from a list

Tags: json, sharepoint, power-automate

I have a document library "Project Files" and a list "PF_Metadata".
I also have Document ID Service active on the site collection.

In Project Files I need to fill the value of the Status field from PF_Metadata.
The document in Project Files(Document ID Value column) corresponds with the column PF_Document_Value_ID in PF Metadata.

I can do it manually with a lookup field, but how can you do this automated?

Answer (score 0):

You could create flow as following pictures show.

In the condition, "Document ID Value" in the Get files(properties only) is equal to PF_Document_Value_ID in the Get items.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks,
The problem then is that a user can have the dovument opened, and the metadate can't update.

We have this issue now, and in the flow I've built a do untill loop that runs every 5 minutes untill it can update.
This isn't really a good solution.

Roland